# Is it a sin to write a verse or hadith incorrectly, and does this imply it's permissible to cheat on an Islamiat exam?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, ayah, cheating

I have seen other questions regarding cheating in exams but my question is only about exam/test of Islamic studies or Islamiat.

Some people say that you can cheat in Islamiat exam/test because it will be a sin to write a verse or hadith in wrong words or in wrong order of words by mistake.

Please clear my confusion that if it is allowed or simply I should not write it if I don't know it in exact words?

Comment: If it's a mistake, how can it be a sin?

Comment: @Ansari If the student knows that he is not sure about what he is writing, then it might be a sin. I am not sure.

Comment: That's ridiculous - should people stop memorizing Qur'an by reciting because they might make a mistake the first few times they recite it? How is any learning possible then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd write the best I recall as the answer and, if i'm not sure of its accuracy, note that down. but if it's not just the wording and i'm not sure at all about the meaning, i'd avoid answering it.

Comment: Seems sensible to me